# Is there a good alternative to Atlassian's FishEye?

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye

I'm a big fan of [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview), unluckily I'm bound to a commercial project and FishEye is simply not in budget. Are there any good alternatives, which have the same features? 
the SCM-backend is an [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)-repository.

Comment: This is absurd. Almost every question I find useful, including this one, has been closed as not constructive.

Comment: VisualSVN Server has file & folder finder in the web interface. See this https://twitter.com/visualsvn/status/1215264724591443970

Comment: Worth noting that Fisheye entered basic maintenance mode: https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/fisheye-and-crucible-are-in-basic-maintenance-mode-987143949.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2015:** Sventon is [`d(ead|ormant)`](https://sventonblog.blogspot.se/), but it's still available at it's [final resting place on github](https://github.com/sventonsvn/sventon).

A non-commercial alternative to Fisheye is the open-source project [Sventon (link to last active snapshot on archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20141012221329/http://sventon.org:80/). I have by now given it a short test install and was pretty amazed by how fast you can set it up. It's just a `.war`-file to drop in a Tomcat 6 container. Still haven't got around to do much with it, though, but it looks quite promising and is really fast.

Here's the feature-list from their homepage:

- Browse and download directories and files
- Source code syntax highlighting for many languages, including Java, HTML, XML, C, Groovy, Pascal/Delphi, VisualBasic, C#, and JavaScript.
- View logs and blame individual files
- Diff your repository files, or view their properties
- Show differences between paths.
- Support for multiple repositories
- Several authentication methods supported, including user based
- Integrates with JIRA, Hudson, Luntbuild and TortoiseSVN
- Easily keep track of changes using the 'latest commit' feature
- Lightning fast search for instantly finding files or log messages, including CamelCase Search
- Flattening of directory structures for quickly finding the directory you're looking for
- Browse inside archive files
- View thumbnails of image files stored in the repository
- Commit notifications via e-mail
- Context sensitive RSS feed support
- Instantly find locked files in the repository
- Convenient tray for handling entries

Comment: As of 2018, the website seems to be gone .

Comment: @UweKeim: replaced the link to the last active archive.org snapshot :)

Answer (score 2):

If PHP do not cause rejection from the first steps, you can see at [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/), [feature-list](http://www.websvn.info/features/) is not much different from Sventon

Comment: Seems to have no updates since 2011.

Comment: Updated fork of WebSVN: https://websvnphp.github.io